# Android can't access a websocket written in PHP

Tags: php, android, websocket

I have written a PHP script which creates a websocket server based on [ghedipunk/PHP-Websockets](https://github.com/ghedipunk/PHP-Websockets). Web clients can access it, but not our Android application.

Here is our PHP code:

```
<?php

require_once './websockets.php';

class BleuWebSocketServer extends WebSocketServer
{
    protected function process($user, $message)
    {
        foreach($this->users as $u)
        {
            if($u != $user)
                $this->send($u, $message);
        }
    }

    protected function connected($user)
    {
        $this->send($user, "PING");
    }

    protected function closed($user)
    {
    }
}

$server = new BleuWebSocketServer("0.0.0.0", "1234");
$server->run();
```

And the Android app code, based on [TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebSocketClient mWebSocketClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        connectWebSocket();
    }

    private void connectWebSocket() {
        URI uri;
        try {
            uri = new URI("ws://192.168.43.47:1234/bleu");
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        mWebSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(uri) {
            @Override
            public void onOpen(ServerHandshake serverHandshake) {
                Log.i("Websocket", "Opened");
                mWebSocketClient.send("Hello from " + Build.MANUFACTURER + " " + Build.MODEL);
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(String s) {
                final String message = s;
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.messages);
                        textView.setText(textView.getText() + "\n" + message);
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onClose(int i, String s, boolean b) {
                Log.i("Websocket", "Closed " + s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {
                Log.i("Websocket", "Error " + e.getMessage());
            }
        };
        mWebSocketClient.connect();
    }

    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.message);
        mWebSocketClient.send(editText.getText().toString());
        editText.setText("");
    }
}
```

The expected result is that at startup, the application joins the websocket and sends the message *Hello from…* that you can see in `onOpen()` method. But this does not happen and it looks like `onOpen()` is never executed, as we does not have any log from this method. The only message we get is "Closed", which comes from `onClose()` method.

When the Android application tries to access the websocket, here is what I see in the script log:

```
Client connected. Resource id #8
Client disconnected. Resource id #8
```

The Android application can access other websocket server like [websocket.org Echo Test](http://www.websocket.org/echo.html), so the problem comes clearly from our server.

What are we doing wrong?

Comment: Well if it can connect and disconnect then it works i would say. What is the problem?

Comment: @greenapps well, the problem is that the application connects and disconnects immediately from the server, so that it can't do anything with the websocket

Comment: You are dumping a lot of code without explaining how you want it to work. And without telling how it flows.

Comment: ,`here is what I see in the script log:`. Strange that time information fails. Such information is important.

Comment: When/how is sendMessage() called?

Comment: The `sendMessage()` method is called when a button in the view is clicked. All the code in Android app seems to work perfectly when joining websocket.org Echo Test, but it totally fails with our websocket :/

Comment: `You are dumping a lot of code without explaining how you want it to work. And without telling how it flows.`

Comment: `Strange that time information fails`. Please tell how long it takes to receive the closed message. And meanwhile you are NOT calling `sendMessage()` is it?

Comment: It comes come immediately after the the _connected_ message.